# How to get the tab name on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am trying to bind a repeater control for each tab on the current page. So on page load, how do I get the tab name for the current tab, so that I can pass the id to the method?

I tried this but it keeps on entering the first if statement for all the other pages. How can I go about this?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (new TabController().GetTabByName("Bachelor Party", PortalId)
                .TabName == "Bachelor Party")
            {
                BindEventType(1, 0, 0, string.Empty);
            }
            else if (new TabController().GetTabByName("Birthday Party", PortalId)
                .TabName == "Birthday Party")
            {
                BindEventType(2, 0, 0, string.Empty);
            }
            else if (new TabController().GetTabByName("Cocktail Party", PortalId)
                .TabName == "Cocktail Party")
            {
                BindEventType(3, 0, 0, string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you seem create a new  TabController and check if the tab name equals tab name, which is always true actually.
You should probably call existing form control and get it's selected tab first. And then check its name.

Comment: Please how do i get selected tab? these is what i did.                                         
var tab = new TabController().GetTabsByPortal(PortalId);                                           tab.selectedtab cannot be found.

Comment: why var tab = new TabController().GetTabsByPortal(PortalId); 
and not 

var tab = TabController1.GetTabsByPortal(PortalId);

Comment: Thanks Jury for your response, i have been able t solve these issuse by checking the currentpage                                                                                 var tab = TabController.CurrentPage;

                    if (tab.TabName == "Bachelor Party")
                    {
                        BindEventType(1, 0, 0, string.Empty);
                    }
                    else if (tab.TabName == "Birthday Party") 
                    {
                        BindEventType(2, 0, 0, string.Empty);
                    }